# How to reference a local absolute file path in html

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website locally using Apache, MySQL and PHP. I have different subfolders and I'm trying to give one absolute reference to my css file from my main header.php includes file.

Inside of header.php I have:

```
<link href="/Users/nicolauria/Sites/sd/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The css file does not load correctly. Developer tools gives me this message "The requested URL /sd/css/style.css was not found on this server."

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Nico

Answer (score 3):

You're loading this via HTTP? Then you're bound to use only "http-space" paths, which means you can **NOT** include the site's document root in urls. e.g.

your site's files are physically on the server in `/home/sites/example.com/html`, which is defined as the document root of the site. When you visit the site and request a file, e.g. `http://example.com/foo/bar.html`, the web browser will send over:

```
GET /foo/bar.html
```

and the webserver will tack on the document root, producing

```
/home/sites/example.com/html/foo.bar.html
```

But note that this path applies **ONLY** within the webserver itself. It will never be accesssible to you in this form. You can only specify directories/files within the site's document root. That means if you requested something like `example.com/home/sites/example.com/other/file.html`, you'd force the server to produce `/home/sites/example.com/html/home/sites/example.com/other/file.html`, etc...

Comment: Thanks Marc! I'm going to look into hosting all the files on Bluehost while I develop the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide an absolute URI then you must:

- Include the scheme (`file://`)
- Accept that many browsers will refuse to load `file:` data onto a page loaded via `http:`/`https:` for security reasons
- Accept that users on other computers won't have access to your filesystem

It is far, far better to host all the resources you need on the webserver.

Comment: Thank you Quentin! I will look into storing all the files on Bluehost.

Answer (score 0):

In Which location your header.php file is located? I mean If you have your header.php file in **sd** folder than use your code like this `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />`

Maybe this link will help you alot
http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/css/style-html.html

Comment: Thank you ZearaeZ!